Automatically turn on and off rarely used services
I have here a minimal-memory, lowest-budget VM setting, where I would like to use a rarely used big service. I think, things would look really much better, if I could simply turn it off if I do not need it (about 99% of the work day).
Fortunately, the tool starts relatively quickly. It is being accessed over a tcp socket.
I think, I would put some socket before it, which could auto-start it if there is a request. It could also auto-stop it if there is no access for a while (some minutes or so).
Can I somehow do it, maybe with some tricky systemd socket configuration?

Yes, that's possible with a systemd.socket. The man systemd.socket page actually is kind of nice, but in short:

You need a something.socket file
You need a something.service file
The socket file needs to be set to Accept=no and should specify a port (ListenStream=)
The service executablke itself needs to accept a connected socket as stdin, or through the systemd file-descriptor passing method (sd_listen_fd)
The service file needs to specify StandardInput=socket or the systemd file passing method needs to be used

There's really fundamentally no way around that: even if your service starts quickly, the other end might already have chosen to close the connection if nothing accepts the attempt; without a listening socket, a program can't know about connection attempts, and only one program might listen to a port. However, on Linux it's possible to accept the connection and pass the resulting file descriptor on to a new process – which is exactly what (x)inted or systemd do to make it possible to enable services via connections.

Ok, but what will turn off the service if there is inactivity?

that is something that nobody but your service "understands", as your service is the only thing on this planet that knows when it's done doing all processing it needed to do. Hence, your service must shut itself down. No big deal, usually.

Yes but that is a specific feature of that service. I think systemd could know, if there is no new request to forward since a while.

@peterh - what does said process do, how would systemd know it's not needed any longer?

@tink It is serving blobs and some dav-like things over http. Systemd could know it that no new http reuest happened since a timeout. Btw, systemd has some socket proxy tool.

what do you mean with "socket proxy tool"? If you mean systemd.socket units with Accept=yes, indeed, these exist, but would need more extensive changes to your service.

and you're assuming systemd should understand anything about the connection. It can't. It literally gives away the socket after accepting the connection; it can't know when the request is done.
